# SKActions not working on subview SKView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I've added an `SKView` as a `subview` in my Sprite Kit game to display the game nodes and content.

```
let skView = SKView()

class GameViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    self.view.addSubview(skView)
```

The `SKView` is added as a `subview` instead of the default way suggested in Sprite Kit projects (the commented code below), because I also have an `MKMapView` that is displayed behind the mostly transparent `SKView`, and otherwise the `MapView` would obscure the game scene.

```
//let skView = self.view as! SKView
```

The Game Scene is then presented on the SKView:

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.

        skView.allowsTransparency = true

        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false

        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        scene.backgroundColor = .clearColor()

        skView.presentScene(scene)            
    }
```

In the main Game Scene, I have a main worldnode, to which I add a bunch of character nodes in a separate function, which is called when the scene is presented (code below). This function also applies rotate and move actions to the character nodes. If I set up the `SKView` that presents the scene using the default Sprite Kit method (`let skView = self.view as! SKView`), this works perfectly, but if I add the presenting scene to the view controller as a `subview` (`let skView = SKView()` and `self.view.addSubview(skView)`), then the actions do not work properly - the character nodes twitch instead of rotating properly, and do not move at all.

Can anyone help me understand why the actions seem not to be functioning when the scene is presented on an `SKView` that is a `subview` of the view controller? (But function fine when the `SKView` is set as `self.view as! SKView`)? I've checked the nodes with `hasActions()` (they do), and everything seems to be in the proper view hierarchy, so I'm a bit stumped.

I'm running the latest iOS 9.0 beta, and Xcode 7.0 beta.

Thanks.

```
func moveCharacters() {
    if characterDic.count > 0 {
        for i in 1...characterDic.count {
            if let characterKey = characterDic["P" + "\(i)"] {
                let characterStatus = Int(characterKey["active"] as! NSNumber)
                if characterStatus == 1 || characterStatus == 2 {

                    if worldNode.childNodeWithName("P" + "\(i)") != nil {
                        worldNode.childNodeWithName("P" + "\(i)")?.removeFromParent()
                    }

                    let characterXPos = CGFloat(characterDic["P" + "\(i)"]!["curX"] as! Double)
                    let characterYPos = CGFloat(characterDic["P" + "\(i)"]!["curY"] as! Double)

                    let characterTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "character1.png")
                    let character = SKSpriteNode(texture: characterTexture)
                    character.position = CGPoint(x: characterXPos, y: characterYPos)
                    character.xScale = 0.2
                    character.yScale = 0.2
                    worldNode.addChild(character)

                    /////////

                    let characterXDest = CGFloat(characterDic["P" + "\(i)"]!["destX"] as! Double)
                    let characterYDest = CGFloat(characterDic["P" + "\(i)"]!["destY"] as! Double)

                    let destLoc = CGPoint(x: characterXDest, y: characterYDest)

                    let distToGo = sqrt(pow((characterXDest - characterXPos),2) + pow((characterYDest - characterYPos),2))

                    let moveNode = SKAction.moveTo(destLoc, duration: Double(distToGo/50))

                    let angle = atan2(((destLoc.y - (character.position.y))), ((destLoc.x - (character.position.x))))

                    let Pi = CGFloat(M_PI)

                    let DegreesToRadians = Pi / 180

                    let rotate = SKAction.rotateToAngle(angle - 90 * DegreesToRadians, duration: 0)

                    character.runAction(rotate)
                    character.runAction(moveNode)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```